# how to take particular character from tamil font in android

Tags: android, fonts, tamil

I am using Tamil font (Bamini) in my application. I can able to use Tamil font in my application like

```
    TextView text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text); // initialize to your textview
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(),"Bamini.ttf");
    text.setTypeface(tf);
    text.setText("m");
```

my problem is i need exact character without typing. Let me explain in detail.
I have to display Tamil character when application loaded and when i click next button another character should display. I am displaying character in text view. since in Tamil font its not in order i cant able to get character in order like A,AA,E,EE. I have to set text for textview dynamically when next button is clicked.

Please help me..Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make Array of characters using this table [Tamil Keyboard Translate Table](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.keyboardtechref/doc/kybdtech/tamil.htm), and then use your logic to convert to Tamil, then load one by one charecter from the Array onClick listner of the button